# Trying to retrieve the first image on Wikipedia pages using Wikipedia API - isn't working specifically for articles on video games?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am attempting to retrieve box art for video game titles from Wikipedia using a GET query and the Wikipedia API. I am using the below query string which seems to be working fine for any other article, such as for the article about the Wii:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Wii&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&format=json&formatversion=2

Which produces the below result:

```json
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 421853,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Wii",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Wii-console.jpg/400px-Wii-console.jpg",
                    "width": 400,
                    "height": 400
                },
                "pageimage": "Wii-console.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However whenever I try it with any article about an individual video game title it isn't working. For example, for Wii Sports:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Wii_Sports&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&format=json&formatversion=2

Which produces the below:

```json
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "fromencoded": false,
                "from": "Wii_Sports",
                "to": "Wii Sports"
            }
        ],
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 5077457,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Wii Sports"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Every other title I try is bringing up the same results.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: This is a weird one.  The example link in the official docs for the Albert Einstein page isn't returning any results either!  https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages#API So it's either a bug on their end or a change that hasn't been properly documented.

Comment: @linda I can't seem to edit that page correctly but the correct link for Einstein is to search on Wikipedia not on mediawiki and this link does return results as expected. I think the issue with that page is just that it's using a relative URL instead of an absolute one. This works: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Albert%20Einstein&pithumbsize=100

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will only get image results when the image is free in the public domain or licensed in such a way that it is free to use and not when it is licensed or fair use.

When I query for `pageprops` on wii, I see a `page_image_free` and indeed, the image on that page is in the public domain. However, on wii sports, it instead has `page_image` which means the license is not free, and indeed the image on that page is fair use which means it's not licensed or free.

Comment: That is correct, but there's a `pilicense=any` parameter for that.

Comment: @Tgr thanks! great point - https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Wii_Sports&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&format=json&formatversion=2&pilicense=any